# Secure communication between Astyanax and Cassandra

Tags: ssl, cassandra, astyanax

Has anyone come up with a way to secure communication between Cassandra and Astyanax client?
SSL is preferred to be able to do client cert auth + encryption...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to assume you've enabled SSL in cassandra and have the keystore file, if not full blog on [enabling SSL in Astyanax here.](http://lyubent.github.io/security/planetcassandra/2013/05/31/ssl-for-astyanax.html)

You need to pass the keystore file and it's password to Astyanax when you are building the Keyspace context:

```
AstyanaxContext<Keyspace> ctx = new AstyanaxContext.Builder()
    .forKeyspace("MyKeyspace")
    // Config parameters
    .withConnectionPoolConfiguration(
         new com.netflix.astyanax.connectionpool.impl.ConnectionPoolConfigurationImpl("MyConnectionPool")
        .setSeeds("127.0.0.1")
        .setSSLConnectionContext(
             new SSLConnectionContext(
             "/path/to/certificate/cassandra_external_trust.jks", // tell Astyanax the fully qualified path to the keystore file C* is using
             "somePassword")))                                    // supply the keystore file's password too
    .buildKeyspace(ThriftFamilyFactory.getInstance());
ctx.start();
```